# CLI plain CSS Minifier, not SASS or LESS

Tags: css, compression, minify

Does anyone know of any CLI CSS Compressors for just normal css files?
Not for SASS/SCSS, or LESS, or Stylus.

I would believe that there would be a compressor available for just compressing style.css into style.min.css?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try [YUI compressor](http://yuilibrary.com/projects/yuicompressor/) ([quick reference](http://developer.yahoo.com/yui/compressor/)). It's pretty straightforward, and supports JavaScript minification as well (can't hurt).

It can also be found [here](http://refresh-sf.com/yui/) as a service.